# Public IP address port forwarding goes to my router's homepage and not my laptop’s server

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, nat, dmz

I am trying to turn my laptop into an internal server to be accessed from anyone on the Internet. But whenever someone types my public IP address into their URL bar it sends them to my router’s config page. I tried port forwarding, NAT forwarding, DMZ to route the traffic directly to my laptop by with no results. Any ideas?

I am using a LOGN HN-DRN1 router. I was trying to forward port 80.

These are the options I get when I go to the router firewall page:

```
  1-IP/Port Filtering
  2-MAC filtering
  3-Port Forwarding
  4-ALG
  5-NAT forwarding
  6-NAT pool
  7-DMZ
  8-IMGP proxy
  9-UPnP
  10-RIP
```

Comment: Turn off your router's Internet/WAN-facing management interface.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I am sorry but again I am an absolute newbie. so is there any way you can give me some reference keywords that I can go hunting for in the router config page.

Comment: I already did "management infterface", maybe: "management web UI" maybe: "The thing you control this $5 router with". ;)   I can't tell you anything about your specific router, as it appears to be a "Radio-Shack Special", with no online documentation (that I can find), but the Management UI settings will (most likely) have nothing to do with the "firewall" settings portion.

Comment: Probably under an "advanced" page of some sort...

Comment: I also have an old speedtouch 585 v6. I went to its user management page but I don't see how to turn it off from the WAN-facing side. http://www.speedtouch.com.br/st585v6/aqvst585v6/manuais/user_guide_st585v6.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As long as your router is manageable using port 80, you can't forward the incoming traffic on this port to other addresses. Go to your router's **"Access Control"** or **"Management"** section and disable router manageability over HTTP port 80 from WAN (if your router supports that). You can also change HTTP management's port to something other than 80 (e.g. 808), then try again.

**WARNING!!!:** *Don't disable HTTP management from LAN zone! otherwise you lose access to your router and have to reset it to factory defaults.*

Answer (score -4):

Find the DHCP client list and locate the private IP of your laptop server, then port forward port 80 to that private IP

Comment: How? Provide specifics